# Bash: Store sed result into array?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

How to fix the following code so that it can store the result of `sed`, which will replace the `_`
with `-`?

My code:

```
names=()
for entry_ in $foo
do
  names+=($entry_ | sed -e "s/_/-/g")
done

echo names
```

Comment: Please try [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) at first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `sed` for this, you can use bash's built-in [parameter expansion + substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) capability to replace all `_` characters with `-`: `${var//_/-}`. You can even use it to do this for the entire list of elements in a single operation, but how you do it depends on what the source variable, `foo`, actually is.

If `foo` is an array (the much better way to do things), you can combine `[@]` ("get me all elements of the array") with the substitution:

```
names=( "${foo[@]//_/-}" )
```

If `foo` is a plain string, and you need to use word splitting to break it into elements for the array, you can do essentially the same thing without the `[@]` ('cause it's not an array) or the double-quotes (which prevent word splitting):

```
names=( ${foo//_/-} )
```

Note: I recommend avoiding word splitting if possible -- it often does something close to what you want, but almost never *exactly* what you want.

P.s. I third the recommendation of [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Among other things, it'll flag anything involving word splitting as a probable mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to get you there.

```sh
names=()

names+=$(echo "hello_world" | sed -e "s/_/-/g")

echo $names
```

Note that you need `$` before echoing your variable.

Also. Look into installing [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for your code editor and it will help you catch sneaky bugs and build better shell programming practices.

Comment: I did ```` before I saw your answer. OK I will try shellcheck. Let me check about whether it has a neovim plugin.